# Query by field A and if field B is not null also query by field B HQL grails

Tags: grails, hql

So I have this query:

```
"from ProductLookupNumber pln left join pln.creator as creator
where (pln.searchNumber like '%" + query + "%') 
or (creator is not null and creator.name like '%" + query + "%')"
```

I'm using grails but for some reason it's returning empty no matter what I write in the input field that submits the query variable.

This next query works fine. But I am not able to filter by the creator's name:

```
from ProductLookupNumber pln where (pln.searchNumber like '%" + query + "%')
```

This other query filters all records that don't have a creator:

```
"from ProductLookupNumber pln " +
"where (pln.searchNumber like '%" + query + "%') " +
"or (pln.creator is not null and pln.creator.name like '%" + query + "%')"
```

The thing is that some ProductLookupNumber records can have a null creator, which is a different instance. So when I submit a query I want it to find all the records that have the search number String OR IF they have a creator, include them if the creator's name matches the submitted variable.

Update:

So I have a table with these records:

---

### SearchNumber  | Creator        |

### 123                     | Honda          |

### 12345                 | MITSU          |

### 45                       | NULL            |

I have a search bar and if they type: 12 and click I'd like to show this:

---

### SearchNumber  | Creator        |

### 123                     | Honda          |

### 12345                 | MITSU          |

If I type Honda this:

---

### SearchNumber  | Creator        |

### 123                     | Honda          |

And if I type 45 this:

---

### SearchNumber  | Creator        |

### 12345                 | MITSU          |

### 45                       | NULL            |

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your domain class for product lookup number specifically declaration of creator  you left join  in one case and in another directly query

Comment: please review my answer and fix your question or delete it and give more time to what it is you are trying to ask

Comment: The editor "ate" the white spaces. What I want to achieve should be more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You are searching through two fields so your entire where statement which is or has to be in a brackets it is this or that or this case and it all needs proper bracketing - pay attention to comments and spacing below to explain

```
   def query =  """from ProductLookupNumber pln left join pln.creator creator
     //Entire thing around brackets here
    where  (  
             //first check
             (pln.searchNumber like '%${query}%' ) 
             // or it is over to creator
             or 
               //creator is null when you search for 45 it returns null
               (creator is null 
                 // or creator is not null and is :
                   or (
                          //is not null and name matches query
                          (
                            creator is not null and 
                             creator.name like '% ${query}%' 

                          )
                      )
                )

       )"""
```

when using `OR` in `HQL` pay attention to brackets - it needs to be done correctly or you will get wrong results. Above should hopefully fix your issue and highlight importance of how each or has its own bracketing but in an overall bigger or brackets

In regards to `join` and `left join`. If creator is a domain object and `is not nullable then join is sufficient. If however it can be`nullable`then left join is required. In your case it can be nullable so it should be`left join`.

**E2A**
Can you do a `println "query is $query"` to see if the query looks correct ?. I tweaked the query given earlier since you had used single "" and I am using """  """  so as it was the query variable I don't think was correctly put into query hence my comment now

Comment: It also shows no records. I'm begining to think that the problem may not be the query but that the view expects a list entities and the query is returning something else. <f:table collection="${productLookupNumberList}" />

Comment: well add println "${results}" or whatever captures the results from the hql to see what it is or println "${results.size()}"

Comment: ${results} = [[123_123AB-25 HONDA, HONDA], [1225-12-25 MITSUBISHI, MITSUBISHI]] and "${results.size()}" = 2 Son not only am I losing the instance but it's still filtering the ones without a creator

Comment: What is `name` in creator is just default data type like String or is name another object within your domain classes ? It is difficult to answer you since unsure what existing criteria was - was creator part of it do you want those that have no creator records as well as those that have creator and creator being the name ? I have updated query - maybe above is more what you are after

Comment: Yes, name is a String. I will update my question to try and show the scenario more clearly. The new query didn't work either. 
${results} = [[12345 null, null]] and "${results.size()}" = 1

Comment: Sorry, this new query doesn't return a list of ProductLookupInstances either. Same issues as with the previews ones:

"${results}" = [[123_123AB-25 HONDA, HONDA], [1225-12-25 MITSUBISHI, MITSUBISHI], [987654_67 null, null], [12345 null, null]]
"${results.size()}" = 4

I got it working differently but I'm not pleased with the logic.

Comment: take a look at the updated query - the previous I don't think was passing in anything as query variable due to my changes to your query statement speech marks

Comment: "${results}" = [[123_123AB-25 HONDA, HONDA], [1225-12-25 MITSUBISHI, MITSUBISHI], [987654_67 null, null], [12345 null, null]]
"${results.size()}" = 4

Same issue as before.
query is:
from ProductLookupNumber pln left join pln.creator creator where  (         (pln.searchNumber like '%12%' )        or       (creator is null               or (                       (                                       creator is not null and               creator.name like '% 12%'                                    )       )))

Comment: the last creator.name like has an extra space but 12 would turn up 12345 null, null] since you have asked for this - and it exists - unsure how 987654_67 null is getting captured - maybe you need to enable sql debugging and run actual query to figure out where

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pleased with the way I got it to work. But I at least I get the list of instances that I wanted to:

```
def where_query = ProductLookupNumber.where {
    searchNumber =~ "%${query}%" || creator.name =~ "%${query}%"
}
def list = where_query.list()
def list2 = criteria.list {
    isNull('creator')
    like("searchNumber", "%${query}%")
}
list.addAll(list2)
```